# Git merge conflict problem - Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result

Tags: git, merge, conflict

How can resolve this merge conflict?

*Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.*

I get this for several files e.g below,

- but it has some modifications only (see below)
- file command cant show any other difference (see below)
- line ending are the same - see the attached picture

> ```
> > diff Amanagement.module.ts Bmanagement.module.ts
> 16d15
> < import { FileExportModule } from '../shared/components/file-export/file-export.module';
> 35,36c34
> <     ManagementRoutingModule,
> <     FileExportModule
> ---
> >     ManagementRoutingModule
>
> BRANCH A
> file /foo/management.module.ts
> /foo/management.module.ts: Java source, ASCII text
>
> BRANCH B
> file /foo/management.module.ts
> /foo/management.module.ts: Java source, ASCII text
> ```

[image]

Thanks for the hints.

Csaba

Comment: I don't know what merge tool you are using, nor why it's showing the merged file as all-question-marks, but the conflict is clear enough: one side changed two lines (deleting two module names), the other side deleted one line and changed one line (to remove a comma and one module name).

Answer (score 0):

I solved by changing to VSCode what could interpret more properly the conflict in this situation.